# Print Bill Invoice After the Submit Button in php

Tags: php, printing

I have two columns `item name` and `amount`. I just click the submit button and then I want to print the invoice. I already set the invoice format and I know `onclick="window.print()` but in this case the page prints everything. I only want to print the invoice format after the submit button.

```
<form method="post">
item name
<input type="text" name="item">
amount
<input type="text" name="amt">
<input type="submit" name="submit">

</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $item = $_POST['item']  ;
    $amt = $_POST['amt']  ;


    // want print I have set the invoice

    }

?>
```

Comment: Using js , onclick on submit button you can getting the I'd of that div which you want to print. Ok and then called particular function that's it.

Comment: On a physical printer, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `JavaScript` instead of `php`. Please put the printing  part inside a div with an id As:

```
<div id="print_setion">
      <h1>Print This Setion Only</h1>
</div>

<input type="button" onclick="printDivSection('print_setion')" value="Print This Setion Only" />
```

and create JavaScript as :

```
function printDivSection(setion_id) {
     var Contents_Section = document.getElementById(setion_id).innerHTML;
     var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;

     document.body.innerHTML = Contents_Section;

     window.print();

     document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
}
```

Note: `innerHTML` get only div section that is inside id `<div id="print_setion">`

Comment: but then he hasn't posted his form, he wants it in PHP I think?

Comment: @Gufran Hasan .. i dont want disply `<h1>Print This Setion Only</h1>` just only print this case

Comment: @safvansaf, okay embed it in PHP script